# Android Studio with flutter has different layouts depending on the project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

My Android Studio has different windows when I open a project.

Project A:
[View Tools Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS09M.png)
[Bottom Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3PvV.png)

Project B:
[View Tools Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzwYE.png)
[Bottom Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGvaw.png)

In project A I have the message and profiler window and I do not have the Build window

In project B I don't have the message and profiler window, but I do have the Build window.

Why does it happen? What did I do in the project that made the Android Studio layout with Flutter different?

Both projects were created in the same week, identical versions, the computer is the same but they open with a different layout.